# Disable radio button list item with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I'm attempting to disable a radio button from an asp `RadioButtonList` using JavaScript. Here is what I have:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbPlanner" runat="server" onclick="deselectRadioListItem('P');" />
```

which calls this client JavaScript `onClick`...

```
function deselectRadioListItem(radioValue) {
    var clientID = ('<%= rblSummaryOptions.ClientID %>');
    for (i = 0; i < '<%= rblSummaryOptions.Items.Count %>'; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).value == radioValue) {
            (clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled === true;
        }
        else
        {
            (clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled === false;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything appears to be working correctly (fires, iterates, if-statements work) however, the radiobutton control is not becoming disabled, even though the logic is hit. What am I missing? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `===` operator is used for comparison. You need to use `=`.

```
function deselectRadioListItem(radioValue) {
    var clientID = ('<%= rblSummaryOptions.ClientID %>');
    for (i = 0; i < '<%= rblSummaryOptions.Items.Count %>'; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).value == radioValue) {
            document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or cleaned up a tiny bit:

```
function deselectRadioListItem(radioValue) {
    var clientID = ('<%= rblSummaryOptions.ClientID %>');
    for (i = 0; i < '<%= rblSummaryOptions.Items.Count %>'; i++) {
        var objCurrentRdo = document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString());

        if (objCurrentRdo.value == radioValue)
            objCurrentRdo.disabled = true;
        else
            objCurrentRdo.disabled = false;
    }
}​
```

**Additional Information:** Check out [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) on MDN.

Comment: I made the change, but it is still not disabling.

Comment: @Ted, are there any errors? If the elements exist and their value equals the radioValue being passed in, the code above should work.

Answer (score 0):

this is for sure wrong.

```
(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled === true;
```

maybe you won to type

```
document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i.toString()).disabled = true;
```

or even better

```
function deselectRadioListItem(radioValue) {
        var clientID = ('<%= rblSummaryOptions.ClientID %>');
        for (i = 0; i < <%= rblSummaryOptions.Items.Count %>; i++) {
                document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i).disabled = 
              document.getElementById(clientID + "_" + i).value == radioValue;
        }
    }
```

you have some bugs here...

Comment: I like it! However, I'm getting.... Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: @Ted is not find the getElementByID elements Make sure that this names exist (the clientID + "_" + i), or show the rendered html to see what they are.